# How can I search for keywords in a source control repositroy

Tags: git, svn, search, version-control, repository

I’m looking for a script or application, which can look up in repository, configuration file, commit history etc. of svn or git using some keywords like bugs, defects, fix etc. the application can take any repository link and the keywords and then produce result. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Subversion you can try

- [SVN-Search](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svn-search/) or
- [SVNQuery](http://svnquery.tigris.org/).

For Git to find all commits where commit message contains the given keyword you can use

```
$ git log --grep=keyword
```

or use the pickaxe-search

```
$ git log -Skeyword
```

[OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/), a source code search and cross reference engine, would be a possible candidate as well.